# This piece was on our driveway and belongs to one of our cars. What is it

Tags: nissan, hyundai, part-identification

My wife found this stamped metal part lying in our driveway so we figure it fell off of one of our vehicles. Either a 2010 Hyundai Veracruz or a 2013 Nissan LEAF. Can anyone help us identify it.  Thank you.

[image: Mystery part]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It is a heat shield of some sort. It's probably to protect the car from the catalytic converter. I couldn't tell you which car it came off of. You'd need to jack the car up and look, but it would probably be more than self evident if you were able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a heatshield from your 2010 Hyundai Veracruz.

Here's the diagram of the exhaust:

[image: Veracruz exhaust]

Based on your photo and the diagram, I am going to guess it's one of these parts:

- 287943J000   Protector - heat rear, rh 28793R
- 287933J000   Protector - heat rear, lh   28793L

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I got under the vehicle and all the heat shields have a dimpled texture instead of stamped metal with the exception of the large shield for the fuel tank and none of them look like they're missing. Since it does look like a heat shield that kind of rules out it being from my LEAF since it's an electric and doesn't have an exhaust system. Will have to bring it with us next time we go to the mechanic for an oil change.